# How to keep width of div the same?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website that rotates different quotes around for a specific amount of seconds, and there is a delay at the beginning. When I load my page, and the first quote comes, it automatically adds a scrollbar to my page, and the page looks bigger. I tried to use css and make the scroll bar be hidden, but it doesn't work. I don't want it to be a set size, because I want it to be a percentage width.

```js
var quotes = [] //different qutoes are in here

  var nextNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  var randNum;

  var equation;
  function genQuote() {
    randNum = nextNum;
    nextNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    while(randNum == nextNum) {
      nextNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    }
    equation = ((quotes[randNum].length / 4.25) * 60)*3;
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[randNum];

    setTimeout(genQuote, equation);
  }

    setTimeout(genQuote, 6000);
```

```html
<p id = "quote"></p>
<!-- tried different styling methods like overflow-x: none, hidden -->
```

So I basically I want there to be no scroll bar, and the quote to be responsive, so no set width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide the horizontal scrollbar, then you can add the following to your css:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I suppose that you tried to add the *overflow-x* property to your *paragraph* element instead of the *body* and that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Good answer, you should also explain why overflow on the paragraph wouldn't work, but would on the body.